# Does Unity LWRP support surface shaders?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I'm using new Unity's Lightweight rendering pipeline.
After creating a material with a new surface shader, created from the drop-down menu, all I see is a pink color.
There is no information at all about creating shaders for LWRP. It looks like unlit shaders are supported without issues, but what about surface shaders?

Comment: It doesn't seem like. Note from [doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptableRenderPipeline.html) *"Note: Built-in and custom Lit Shaders do not work with the Lightweight Render Pipeline. Instead, LWRP has a new set of standard shaders
. If you upgrade a current Project to LWRP, you can upgrade built-in shaders to the new ones."*

Comment: @Programmer I would expect it to be mentioned explicitly, with some examples of how to migrate surface shaders to LWRP.

Comment: It's still new and can change anytime. I am sure they will add more information about that when it's mature enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Feature Comparison Table](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.lightweight@6.5/manual/lwrp-builtin-feature-comparison.html), Surface Shaders are not supported in LWRP.

I didn't find examples of surface shaders migration.

> **Feature**                 | **Unity Built-in render pipeline** | **LWRP**
>
> **Surface Shaders** | Yes                                             | Not supported